# HttpClient slash before path

Tags: angular, angular-httpclient

Is there a difference between invoking Angular HttpClient with and without slash prefix at the beginning of the path?

i.e.: is the result of below invocations differ in any way?

```
httpClient.get<Something>('/api/my/path');// with slash prefix

httpClient.get<Something>('api/my/path');// without slash prefix
```

Comment: check if it forms a complete API URL in the network that you want to invoke.

Answer (score 1):

Yes there's a difference, and it depends on your `base URI` (*which I don't see in your example*)

A rule of thumb; if your Api's base URI ends with no slash, the 1st line will work and the 2nd wont. However, if it has already a slash, both lines would work (*AFAIK*).

1. API's base URI = http://blabla.com

- First result: `http://blabla.com/api/my/path`
- Second result: `http://blabla.comapi/my/path` (*I think it doesn't make sense*)

---

2. API's base URI = http://blabla.com/

- First result: `http://blabla.com//api/my/path` (*Generally, that could work*)
- Second result: `http://blabla.com/api/my/path`

---

*Your `base URI` is your backend server's exposed API (starting from `http(s)://` root)*